# How to use pattern for phone number in an html input?

Tags: html, forms, input

I'm trying to use pattern instead of regex in my code where the number must start with 09 and has a limit of 11 but most I see are regex and pattern inside the form are few but doesn't seem to work like this one that I found which is from an old video. How should I fix it?

```
<input class="form-design" name="phone" type="number" id="phone" pattern="(09)[0-9]{11}" placeholder="Phone Number*" required="">
```

Comment: Can you provide example inputs that should/shouldnt work, or explain what isn't working? Is the leading `09` included in the 11 characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```html
<input class="form-design" name="phone" id="phone" pattern="^09[0-9]{9}$" placeholder="Phone Number*" required="">
```

Because you're defining a pattern for this tag you shouldn't use `type=number`.

`^09[0-9]{9}$` means from the beginning to the end of the input it should start with `09` and after that, it should contain (11 -2 = 9) other numbers.

Comment: tysm @atena for explaining and giving a solution, no wonder other patterns that I've tried didn't work because the ``type="number"`` exist